# JSFiddle.net Am I using this correctly?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I put this code in the JavaScript box on www.jsfiddle.net and hit "run," but nothing happened. It works fine when I test it in Firebug, so why not jsfiddle.net  Am I using jsfiddle.net incorrectly?

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
return Array.prototype.reverse.apply(this.split('')).join('');
}

"box".reverse();
```

Here I'm trying to save a fiddle. I click run and it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/qnjP3/

Answer (score 3):

Well, try `alert("box".reverse())`; Your code *did* work, there was nothing to show it. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7PR9/)

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Vp5SF/

You probably didn't put an alert around your string. Since right now your method only returns the string so you don't have any indication that anything is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to create some output, don't you?

jsfiddle is not a JavaScript console. Either append the output do the DOM or print it to the browser's console.

jsfiddle lets you create a website with HTML, JavaScript and CSS on the fly, but nothing more. If you put your code above in a basic HTML file and open it with your browser, you would not see any output either.

It might be helpful to read the [*documentation*](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: o.k., thanks, I'm a bit of a newbie, thought it would work like the console.

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit green with JS, I had the same notion about JSFiddle ...

Here's a tool that suits a bit better for that IMO ... [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/OboGacA/1/edit?js,console,output) (I took the liberty of putting your code in the above example).

The benefit is that you can use console in jsbin :).